# 403 AccessDenied on Amazon S3 delete proctected folder

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hive, emr

I have one folder in `amazon s3` on which i restricted the permission of deleting any folder. But, now what happened is i am not able create any folder using hive script. This hive query create one temporary folder under the name of `_tmp.customerlevel`. Which it tries to delete once it finishes the map reduce job. But, due to restriction of delete hive query gets failed. Can anyone tell me the workaround for this so that i can maintain the delete protected permission as well as i can write the data using hive script?

```
Insert overwrite directory 's3://logs/customerlevel' select * from customer;

REST.DELETE.OBJECT logs/_tmp.customer "DELETE /logs%2F_tmp.customerlevel HTTP/1.1" 403 AccessDenied
```

Answer (score -2):

you could try to create the temp folder into another bucket to which your user have access to remove.

Comment: @Paul Well, i don't want to create another temp folder.